# How to send Serialized product data to a new product creation on the WooCommerce API?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I am working with the WooCommerce API to create a new product listing, all of it is working perfectly except when trying to send a serialized array as a value for some meta-data.

In my code I pass the meta value like this:

```
serialize(
array(
    'gtin' => trim('3056560000018')
))
```

Which as expected gives me the string '**a:1:{s:4:"gtin";s:13:"3056560000018";}**'

The problem is when that string is submitted over the API and the new product is created, the value in the database is '**s:38:"a:1:{s:4:"gtin";s:13:"3056560000018";}";**'

Am I doing something wrong here? I cannot get my head around what WooCommerce must be doing again to my data!

Comment: use json_encode for the same purpose.

Comment: So replace my serialize() function with json_encode?

Comment: according to Woo documentation you send data in a simple array. https://prnt.sc/w5ifx7
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#create-a-product

Comment: I am actually working with meta data which for a value says string?